# C++ Using INT32: Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: c++, integer

I am currently learning C++ and I am curious if there is a fix to the warning I am getting.

I am using **Int32** to define my integers. I receive the following error when trying to set a variable the length of a string utilising the **.length()** function.

The line of code in question is as follows:

```
int32 HiddenWordLength = MyHiddenWord.length();
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Note:  lengths are usually **unsigned** quantities.  The `int32_t` type is a **signed** quantity.  You may have loss of precision because a *signed* type usually reserves at least 1 bit for the sign.  Think about it, can the length of a word be negative?  So, why are you using a signed value for a length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string.length() returns a value of type size_t (which is defined as unsigned int). The compiler throws a warning because your Int32 variable might not be able to hold the value returned from the .length() method, as the Int32 type can hold values of the range –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 whereas the size_t type (unsigned int) can have values from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Answer (score 1):

`MyHiddenWord.length();` is not returning an **int32** type, the compiler will silently adapt/convert that into an **int32** but is making you aware that you can loss information with that implicit operation.